# Renaming XML elements in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, renaming, rexml

How does one go about renaming an XML element using REXML or another Ruby library?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Nokogiri**:

```
my_node.node_name = "new_name"
```